# How can i make private destructor from singleton using shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, singleton

i tested two type of singleton from C++17

first is unique_ptr second is shared_ptr

these have to work with private constructor and destructor cause nobody can't change any instance status

i finaly successed to compose unique_ptr version but shrared is not done

shared_ptr version makes error

error is **'Singleton2::~Singleton2()' is private within this context' { __p->~_Up(); }**

how can i make shared_ptr singleton?

here's code

```
class Singleton1
{
    public:
    static Singleton1& GetInstance() 
    {
        if(!mFlag)
        {
            mFlag = true;
            mSingle = std::make_unique<Singleton1>(Singleton1(1));
        }

        return *mSingle.get();
    }

    private:
    friend std::unique_ptr<Singleton1>::deleter_type;

    Singleton1(int n) 
        : mNum(n)
    {
        std::cout << "this is unique_ptr singleton" << std::endl;   
    }

    ~Singleton1() = default;

    private:
    const int mNum;
    inline static bool mFlag;
    inline static std::unique_ptr<Singleton1> mSingle;
};
```

```
class Singleton2
{
    public:
    static Singleton2& GetInstance() 
    {
        if(!mFlag)
        {
            mFlag = true;
            mSingle = std::make_shared<Singleton2>(Singleton2(1));
        }

        return *mSingle.get();
    }

    private:
    Singleton2(int n) 
        : mNum(n)
    {
        std::cout << "this is shared_ptr singleton" << std::endl;   
    }

    ~Singleton2() = default;

    private:
    const int mNum;
    inline static bool mFlag;
    inline static std::shared_ptr<Singleton2> mSingle;
};
```

```
int main()
{
    Singleton1& res = Singleton1::GetInstance();
    Singleton2& res = Singleton2::GetInstance();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please add includes to make it easier for others to compile your code.

Comment: If you want the destructor of `Singleton` to be `private`, but also want `std::shared_ptr<Singleton>` then `Singleton` needs to declare whatever is deleting it as a `friend`.    If you haven't specified a deleter when constructing the `std::shared_ptr<Singleton>`, then that `friend` should be `std::shared_ptr<Singleton>`.  Otherwise, the `friend` should be the (type of) the specified deleter (if any).     This does mean that you can't construct a `shared_ptr<Singleton>` with a custom deleter unless that deleter is a `friend`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom deleter and make that `friend` of `Singleton2`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Singleton2
{
    struct Deleter {
        void operator()(Singleton2* ptr){ delete ptr;}
    };
    friend Deleter;
    public:
    static Singleton2& GetInstance() 
    {
        if(!mFlag)
        {
            mFlag = true;
            mSingle = std::shared_ptr<Singleton2>(new Singleton2(1),Deleter{});
        }

        return *mSingle.get();
    }

    private:
    Singleton2(int n) 
        : mNum(n)
    {
        std::cout << "this is shared_ptr singleton" << std::endl;   
    }

    ~Singleton2() = default;

    private:
    const int mNum;
    inline static bool mFlag;
    inline static std::shared_ptr<Singleton2> mSingle;
};


int main()
{
    //Singleton1& res = Singleton1::GetInstance();
    Singleton2& res = Singleton2::GetInstance();

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YPex95x6h)

---

However, consider to simply make the destructor public. As the pointer is encapsulaed there is no danger of someone *accidentally* destroying the object. And if they want to do it on purpose, they will find a way, whether the destructor is `private` or not. `private` is not a way to prevent someone by all possible means to access the function. Its rather a way to unambigously inform others that they should not play tricks to access the method. And because you do not hand the pointer to the caller, they'd also have to "play tricks" when the destructor is public.

---

PS: I suggest you to use the Meyers Singleton where the instance is stored as function local `static` variable. It is thread-safe while your `GetInstance` is not.

Comment: I clearly understood what’s problem
I missed about feature of singleton 
It’s belong to class not instance. so even if i call destructor it still alive... 
and i’ll serch for scott meyers thread-safe singleton
I really appreciate you to sharing time!

Comment: @StarvingDays "I clearly understood what’s problem I missed about feature of singleton It’s belong to class not instance. so even if i call destructor it still alive" sorry, I dont understand what you mean. After you called a destructor the object is no longer alive. The static member will be destructed when the program terminates afaik. Though there is no point in using a shared pointer because there is nothing shared